# Swift | How to add Trailing Space to UILabel programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to add to a `UILabel` a Trailing space programmatically. At the moment I'm trying this:

```
let trailingMargin = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myUILabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, 
     relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, 
     attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)

myUILabel.addConstraint( trailingMargin )
```

But my app always crashes.

`myUILabel` is in a view and I want that it has a:

```
Trailing Space to: Superview
Equals: 20
```

Any advice?

Comment: When are you doing this? Are myUILabel and view non nil?

Comment: No, I'm doing it in viewDidLoad() ...

Answer (score -3):

### How to add a trailing space to UILabel text

Although your question is slightly confusing would not this work for you?

```
func addSpace(inout myLabel : UILabel) {
    self.myLabel.text = "\(self.myLabel.text) "
}
```

FYI: `inout` means you are passing by reference - thus the variable passed in can be modified by the function

Comment: I want to add the trailing space to the UILabel not to the text. The UILabel's trailing space to the Superview.